# Experiencing OnClick() issues with JSInterop in Blazor when creating a rich text editor

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I created a blog application and am converting it into a note based application. I'm fairly new to Blazor and am experimenting around with it. I learned about JSInterop which has helped me a lot since Blazor has little resources on text editors other than third party extensions (which I am trying to avoid).

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="main-content">
        <!--Text Editor Header-->
        <div class="text-editor-header">
            <button @onclick="showChange" type="button" class="btn" data-element="bold">
                <i class="fa fa-bold"></i>
            </button>
            <button @onclick="showChange" type="button" class="btn" data-element="justifyFull">
                <span class="fa fa-align-justify"></span>
            </button>
            <button @onclick="showChange" type="button" class="btn" data-element="insertImage">
                <span class="fa fa-image"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

C# code:

```
async Task showChange()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "buttonPressed");
    }
```

JSInterop.js:

```
function buttonPressed() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    elements.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let command = element.dataset['element'];

            if (command == 'createLink' || command == 'insertImage') {
                let url = prompt('Enter the link here:', 'http://');
                document.execCommand(command, false, url);
            } else {
                document.execCommand(command, false, null);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

The problem I am experiencing is I have to click the button twice for it to work in the first place, plus the image button is calling the prompt multiple times and doesn't even put an image into the document.

I understand @OnClick only needs to be clicked once to work, and so I believe it has to do something with JSInterop. I tried doing some research into if I could just not use a function for it (call without OnClick) to see if it would help but I couldn't find anything. I also believe it could be a browser problem, but I'm not sure.
Would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am experiencing is I have to click the button twice for it to work in the first place

Your JS function `buttonPressed` registers a `click` handler on each button every time it is called

- on click one it registers the click handlers for the first time

> the image button is calling the prompt multiple times

- click two+ registers the click handlers again, plus the previously registered click handler(s) run

> doesn't even put an image into the document.

- It probably does, but every time you click a button Blazor will re-render the component/page - and replace the contents of your editable div with nothing - so you do not see it.

Recommendations:

Place `<div class="content" id="content" contenteditable="true"></div>` in its own component and implement `protected override bool ShouldRender() => false` so the div is added to the dom, then never re-rendered by Blazor.

Change your button handler

```cs
async Task showChange(string command)
{
  await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "buttonPressed", command);
}
```

and your JS function

```js
function buttonPressed(command) {
  if (command == 'createLink' || command == 'insertImage') {
    let url = prompt('Enter the link here:', 'http://');
    document.execCommand(command, false, url);
  } else {
    document.execCommand(command, false, null);
  }
}
```

Now each button can be changed:

```html
<button @onclick='@(() => showChange("insertImage"))' type="button" class="btn">
  <span class="fa fa-image"></span>
</button>
```